# MySQL Minecraft Bukkit Error because not executing properly

Tags: java

The Error: http://pastebin.com/G6zZhNMi

```
public void playerProfileExists(Player player) throws SQLException {
    final String queryCheck = "SELECT * FROM `playerdata` WHERE player = ?";
    final PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
    ps.setString(1, player.getName());
    final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

    resultSet.next();

    final String name = resultSet.getString("player");

    if(name == null){
        System.out.println("Player doesn't exist");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Player exists!");
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? There is some SQL error on the report I pasted.

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: Or at least post the error.  People here do not have your test environment to test the code... exceptions help.

Comment: I did post the error link. I posted it in a pastebin because it was too messy. Sorry, I should have made it more noticeable I guess.

Comment: @dxNeil Why the unaccept? doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `resultSet.next()` before calling `resultSet.getString("player");`

Comment: I just added that, so my now code is: http://pastebin.com/ehMCh054 and that gives me an error of: http://pastebin.com/LmtWyba4

Comment: have you checked if `resultSet.next()` returns true?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void playerProfileExists(Player player) throws SQLException {
    final String queryCheck = "SELECT * FROM `playerdata` WHERE player = ?";
    if(player != null){
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
        ps.setString(1, player.getName());
        ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            String name = resultSet.getString("player");
            System.out.println("Player " + name + " exists!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Player doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

Try it like that - also - you don't have to make every variable `final` - only makes sense for the `queryCheck`-String because this won't.

if `resultSet.next()` wouldn't give you a result -> there is no player. Also check if the `player` you get is not `null` so you can't get a `NullPointerException`.